# Angular return value from function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a weird situation.
I have the following part of html:

```
<div><span> {{ getTitle(story.date); }}</span> </div>
```

Now this is the controller function:

```
$scope.getTitle= function (storyDate) {
        var year = new Date(storyDate).getFullYear();
        if (!$scope.sectionTitleYear.contains(year)) {
            $scope.sectionTitleYear.push(year);
            return year;
        }
        else {
            return '';
        }
    };
```

and this is the declaration of `sectionTitleYear`:

```
$scope.sectionTitleYear = [];
```

now when i run this code, the return value is the right one, but in the html i get empty string.
Whenever i remove the push line code. this code work's fine.
This is the push line code that i removed:

```
$scope.sectionTitleYear.push(year);
```

Please advise me what to do.

Comment: Does `$scope.story.date` exist?

Comment: Small hint: Returning the empty string from your function is unnecesary, the ng-bind directive will not throw any errors when you're returning undefined from a function. As to your original question, try debugging that piece of code

Comment: Dan - yes $scope.story.date has value. when i remove the push code line to $scope.sectionTitleYear so this work.

Comment: Nexus - Tahnk for you tip;)

Answer (score 0):

You return the year only if it's not in `$scope.sectionTitleYear`, so of course it will work if you remove this line - This will prevent the year from being pushed to the array.

If you say that after you remove this line the code is working, perhaps you should always return the year, something like this:

```
$scope.getTitle= function (storyDate) {
    var year = new Date(storyDate).getFullYear();
    if (!$scope.sectionTitleYear.contains(year)) {
        $scope.sectionTitleYear.push(year);
    }
    return year;
};
```

Comment: Yes you right, but i didn't say that i have  a lot of years that duplicates. And I want to show only the first year every time .

Comment: @AnanasPie - Not sure I understand but if you want to show the first year then you need to replace `return year;` with `return $scope.sectionTitleYear.length ? $scope.sectionTitleYear[0] : '';`

Comment: Hi All, I understood what my problem was. Here is JsFiddle for my problem - http://jsfiddle.net/478nxc0c/3/.. I read that digest run functions randomly, thus raised my problem.